# Select a next or previous record on a dataframe (PySpark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe that has a list of timestamps (partitioned by uid, ordered by timestamp). Now, I'd like to query the dataframe to get either previous or next record.

```
df = myrdd.toDF().repartition("uid").sort(desc("timestamp")) 
df.show()
+------------------------+-------+
|uid         |timestamp          |
+------------------------+-------+
|Peter_Parker|2020-09-19 02:14:40|
|Peter_Parker|2020-09-19 01:07:38|
|Peter_Parker|2020-09-19 00:04:39|
|Peter_Parker|2020-09-18 23:02:36|
|Peter_Parker|2020-09-18 21:58:40|
```

So for example if I were to query:

```
ts=datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 19, 0, 4, 39)
```

I want to get the previous record on (2020-09-18 23:02:36), and only that one.
How can I get the previous one?
It's possible to do it using withColumn() and diff, but is there a smarter more efficient way of doing that? I really really don't need to calculate diff for ALL events, since it is already ordered. I just want prev/next record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter and order by, and then limit the results to 1 row:

```
df2 = (df.filter("uid = 'Peter_Parker' and timestamp < timestamp('2020-09-19 00:04:39')")
         .orderBy('timestamp', ascending=False)
         .limit(1)
      )

df2.show()
+------------+-------------------+
|         uid|          timestamp|
+------------+-------------------+
|Peter_Parker|2020-09-18 23:02:36|
+------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Or by using `row_number` after filtering :

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df1 = df.filter("timestamp < '2020-09-19 00:04:39'") \
        .withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.desc("timestamp")))) \
        .filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")

df1.show()

#+------------+-------------------+
#|         uid|          timestamp|
#+------------+-------------------+
#|Peter_Parker|2020-09-18 23:02:36|
#+------------+-------------------+
```